# Is this proof valid? "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" - John M. LEE

Tags: general-topology

I tried to prove the following proposition but I am not very sure if it is valid or not.

Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $A \subseteq X$. If $p \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ then every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

It corresponds to the proposition 2.39 in "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by John M. LEE.
In this proposition a neighborhood of $p$ refers to an open set that contains $p$.

Proof by induction:
Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A \subseteq X$. Let $p \in X$ be a limit point of $A$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $p$.

Hypothesis $H(n)$: "There exist $n$ different elements of $A$, $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ in $U$ with $\forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, $x_i \ne p$."

Let's show that $H(2)$. Since $p$ is a limit point of $A$, there exists a point $x_1 \ne p$ from $A$ in $U$. Hence, there exist a neighborhood $V$ of $x_1$ and a neighborhood $W$ of $p$ such that $V \cap W = \emptyset$ (Hausdorff property). Since $W \cap U$ is a neighborhood of $p$, there exists a point $x_2 \ne p$ from $A$ in $W \cap U \subseteq U$. We have $(W \cap U) \cap V = \emptyset$, so $x_1 \ne x_2$. And we have $x_1 \ne p$, $x_2 \ne p$. Hence $H(2)$.

Now assume $H(n)$: "There exist $n$ different elements of $A$, $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ in $U$ with $\forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, $x_i \ne p$."

The set $X \backslash\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ is open because the finite set $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ is closed. So $U \cap (X \backslash \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\})$ is a neighborhood of $p$. Hence there exists a point $x_{n+1} \ne p$ from A in $U \cap (X \backslash \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}) \subseteq U$. We have that $x_{n+1}$ is different from $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, we also have $x_{n+1} \ne p$. Therefore $H(n+1)$.

For all $n \geq 2$, $H(n)$, so $U$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

Comment: This seems correct, but can't you just use your same idea to give a one-line proof by contradiction?

Comment: Ted Shifrin is right. If there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $F = U \cap A$ is finite, then $U \setminus F$ would be a neighborhood of $p$ containing no point of $A$. But we must be aware that the fact that finite subsets of Hausdorff spaces (or more generally $T_1$-spaces) are closed requires a *proof by induction*.

Comment: I understand your proof, I just have the same question as for Paul Cottalorda, the proof works well if $p$ is not in $A$. If $p$ is in $A$, we should consider $F' = F \backslash \{p\}$ instead of $F$ and the proof will also works for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct. You don't need to start your induction with $H(2)$. You have $H(1)$ for free with the definition of a limit point.

There is also a subtility in the proof, which is that $\lbrace x_1, \ldots, x_n \rbrace$ is closed **because** $X$ is Hausdorff. This is, in fact, true for a larger class of spaces called $T_1$-spaces (which all Hausdorff spaces are), but this isn't true in general.

As stated by Ted Shifrin, you also have an elegant proof by contradiction :

Suppose there exist $V$ a neighborhood of $p$ such that $V \cap A = \lbrace x_1, \ldots, x_n \rbrace$.

Suppose that $p$ is one of the $x_i$. Since $X$ is Haussdorf, there exist a  neighborhood $V' \subset V$ of $p$ such that neither of the other $x_j$ is in $V'$. We then have $V' \cap A = \lbrace p \rbrace$, which contradicts the premise that $p$ is a limit point.

If $p \not \in V \cap A$, since $X$ is Haussdorf, there exist $n$ neighborhoods $V_1, \ldots V_n$ of $p$ all included in $V$ such that $x_i \not \in V_i$ for each $i$. Their intersection is a neighborhood of $p$ that does not intersect $A$, which is absurd since $p$ is a limit point.

Comment: I just have question about the proof by contradiction. When you take the intersection of the $V_i$, we know that the points $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_n$ are not in this intersection but does it mean that the intersection with $A$ is empty? If we take the intersection $ I = V \cap V_1 \cap ... \cap V_n$ (which is a neighborhood of $p$) then we are sure that $I \cap A$ is empty. And then the proof is finished. I also would like to add that $p$ can be an element of $A$, so in this case instead of empty we should verify that the intersection is $\{p\}$. Am I right?

Comment: You are absolutely right, there is a missing assumption in my proof which is that $V_i \subset V$ and you must also formally prove that the case $p \in A$ is not possible, I will edit my answer.